# How to change the From address when a case is created

Tags: email, case, notification

When a SF user creates a case for a particular contact, and check notify check box to the contact person.

It will send the mail from the current logged in user's mail address.

But i want to send mails that case is created to the customer from the mail id support@xyz.com

Is this possible in Salesforce ?

I have tried email alerts in workflow for this which is a manual process when we can decide the , I have also tried org-wide-defaults when the subsequent reply conversation in mail thread we can have from address as support@xyz.com.

But i want the first mail when the case is created which will be sent automatically to the customer when the send notification check box is checked from the mail address support@xyz.com irrespective of any SF user creates that case or any user has logged in.

How to set this system email address ?

Is this option not yet developed ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Logged in user > My Settings(Left Panel) > Email > My Email Settings > Here change the email address

enter image description here

Now if the customer receives mail from this supporttest@abc.com mail id but the logged in user email id will be diffrent. Hope this helps[image]